# Can oozie ignore a missing input file?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

In my oozie coordinator.xml file, I have the following defined as the input directory:

```
<property>
    <name>countingHourlyInputDir</name>
    <value>${coord:dataIn('hourly-input')}/*Pattern1*,${coord:dataIn('hourly-input')}/*Pattern2*</value>
</property>
```

This matches files in the directory where the filename matches either 'Pattern1' or 'Pattern2'.  If the directory contains files Pattern1 files AND Pattern2 files, my jobs run without issue.  However, if the directory contains only Pattern1 files OR Pattern2 files, my job fails, and I get an error like this:

> Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class
>   [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain], main() threw
>   exception, Input Pattern
>   hdfs://hdfsPath/logs/2012/07/09/02/*Pattern1* matches 0 files
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input
>   Pattern
>   hdfs://hdfsPath/logs/2012/07/09/02/*Pattern1* matches 0 files

Is there a way to tell Oozie to ignore this error so that MapReduce jobs are still performed on the files that match Pattern2 rather than failing the whole job?

---

**UPDATE:**

I figured out the solution to this on my own, and I'll document what I did in case someone else runs into this problem later.

I created a class called RegexPathFilter that implements PathFilter and Configurable.  I pass this filter into the hadoop job by specifying the *mapred.input.pathFilter.class* property in the oozie workflow.xml.  Here's my class and my configuration snippets:

```
public class RegexPathFilter implements PathFilter, Configurable {

    public static final String CONF_REGEX_PROPERTY = "regexPathFilter.regex";
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(RegexPathFilter.class);
    private String _regex;
    private Configuration _conf;

    public RegexPathFilter() {

    }

    @Override
    public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
        _conf = conf;
        //get regex from Configuration
        _regex = _conf.get(CONF_REGEX_PROPERTY);
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConf() {
        return _conf;
    }

    public boolean accept(Path path) {
        if(_regex == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("RegexPathFilter must be given a regex to filter with.");
        }

        boolean matches = path.toString().matches(_regex);

        LOG.info(path + (matches ? " matches " : " does NOT match ") + _regex);
        return matches;
    }
}
```

workflow.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.input.pathFilter.class</name>
    <value>com.company.project.hadoop.util.RegexPathFilter</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>regexPathFilter.regex</name>
    <value>.*(Pattern1|Pattern2).*</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this issue is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8870

I was also facing this same problem and solved it by making a slight change in the pattern and zero code.

Replace

```
<property>
    <name>countingHourlyInputDir</name>
    <value>${coord:dataIn('hourly-input')}/*Pattern1*,${coord:dataIn('hourly-input')}/*Pattern2*</value>
</property>
```

with

```
<property>
    <name>countingHourlyInputDir</name>
    <value>{${coord:dataIn('hourly-input')}}/{*Pattern1*,*Pattern2*}</value>
</property>
```

After this replacement, hadoop will throw an error only if directory contains files matching neither pattern1 nor pattern2.